# Use django for one page on a website?

Tags: python, django

I have a small app I would like to build as a project to learn more about web development. Its an app where people can register etc, and add information about themselves (database needed) and their location on a webmap (using leaflet library). The app will be a single page application that the user navigate to via a link on the site that today is already live.

I got a comment from one i know not to use php. Since I am learning python I was thinking maybe to use that for the server side bits. Is it a good idea to use django or other python framework when it will only be used on a single page of the site, is it even possible (very green on this)? Or should i just stick to php for a project this size?

Any input would appreciated

Comment: If the purpose of the project is to learn, use whichever technology you want to learn more about.

Comment: even though this a heavily opinion based question and not even a question for stack overflow, Django might me a a bit overkill for a single page. You may better take a look on other frameworks like flask for this.

Comment: Definitely opinion based. If you know a more suited community for my question I will post there. I don't want to interfere to much with the site that is live today, is it possible to have just one part of the webpage use django? php is already supported on the server and maybe easier to get going with without too much config. But I would like to learn more about python and saw it as an opportunity.

Comment: Maybe go find a chat room that would support opinion based questions. Seeing how chat rooms are less strict than the main site..

Comment: Highly opinion based indeed (don't get me started on php <g>), and while Django is a great framework it might indeed be overkill here (flask might be lighter). In all cases, do consider the hosting issues - you need a host that offers proper Python support (preferably with virtualenv or something alike).

Answer (score 2):

If all you wanted to do was create a static page (something simple that queries a database and displays results with no user input) then PHP would definitely be much easier. It's much, much, MUCH easier to deploy than web apps-- just drop your .php files in /var/www/html and you're set. Apache runs on anything.

Once you're in the realm of needing user accounts, management, etc. or possibly even expansion of scope in the future then Django becomes a more likely candidate. I love Django but deployment of Python/Ruby apps can be a major pain (if not impossible) depending on many factors in your target environment. It looks deceptively easy to get something running when you're using the built-in webserver where everything just works, but in production you may find your host doesn't offer (or you can't compile) mod_wsgi, only has mod_python (incompatible with modern Django), won't run nginx, can't use gunicorn, etc.

Every cheap web host offers PHP support out of the box. If you want support for apps written in Python/Ruby, sometimes you need to pay for additional services (if not running a VPS or EC2 instance).

Basically, there are more factors involved than just the number of pages you intend to write. You really need to evaluate what you're buying into with either avenue.

Comment: "Every cheap web host offers PHP support out of the box." : yes, with different (often incompatible) versions, settings and libraries support. And then they update php / their settings / libraries without warning and your app breaks. The truth is: whatever the technology, cheap web hosting solutions are a PITA. But yes, even I sometimes advised peoples to go for a PHP solution if the app is dead simple and not business critical and safety not an issue and they don't have the resources (money, skills etc) to run a dedicated hosting. That still leaves very few use for PHP actually <g>

Comment: Thanks guys, many valid points. Sorry that my question does not quite fit this forum. Will consider that in future posts. It definitely put me in the right direction though. Think i will go with php for now and see how it goes. In the initial step security is not really an issue and the functionality will be fairly simple to start. Thanks

Comment: @geogrow just beware, "simple" projects tend to grow in rather unpredictable ways and then selling a complete rewrite / technology change to the stakeholders (who are usually totally illiterate when it comes to technology) might prove quite difficult...